# Existing irreducible elements infinitely in an infinite commutative domain with unit.

Tags: commutative-algebra

I want to know if there exist infinitely many irreducible elements in an infinite commutative domain with unit. In other words, is the following statement true?

> Let $R$ be an infinite commutative domain with unit.
> Then, $\# \{ a \in R \mid a$ is an irreducible element of $R \} = \infty$

This question is not an assignment, but is just a question of me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Not always true: it isn't true when $R$ is an infinite field, as in that case there are *no* irreducible elements (a more subtle example with no irreducible elements is in a comment to this answer). So probably you meant to require that $R$ is not a field.

You probably also meant to ask whether, when $R$ is not a field, there have to be infinitely many irreducibles that *are not unit multiples of each other*. That too has counterexamples: there are infinite domains with only *one* irreducible element up to unit multiples. Such rings can be found among the subrings of $\mathbf Q$: for each prime $p$, let $R_p = \{a/b : a, b \in \mathbf Z, p \nmid b\}$.  These are the fractions that can be reduced mod $p$. Its usual name is the localization of $\mathbf Z$ at $p$, and in this ring $p$ is irreducible and every prime other than $p$ is a unit.

The rings $R_p$ are examples of discrete valuation rings (DVRs), which all have just one irreducible element up to unit multiples.  They are also examples of local rings (rings with one maximal ideal).

In a similar way there are rings with any finite number of irreducibles: when $k \geq 1$ and $p_1,\ldots, p_k$ are $k$ different prime numbers, the set of fractions $a/b$ where $b$ is not divisible by any $p_i$ is a ring in which $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ are the only irreducibles up to unit multiple and they aren't unit multiples of each other.  These rings are called semi-local rings (finitely many maximal ideals).

Comment: A less trivial example would be the ring of algebraic integers.

Comment: Thank you for answering or commenting to my question. And I can undewrstand all your examples.

Comment: One may wonder why Euclid's proof does not work in general: $p_1\cdots p_k+1$ might be a unit and so not have any irreducible factors!